# How to disable controls within a page and prevent typing text

Tags: jquery

I want to disable all controls in a page using jQuery:

```
$("form").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

But I can still type text on each input control.

How can I solve it?
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$("form *").prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable `all the input types like text, checkbox, radio etc` you can use input within form.

```
$("form input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```